# Aligning 2 columns next to each other in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to simply get 2 boxes next to each other, one to the left, the other to the right. Then the mytitle box will expand to full width on mobiles.

Do I need to add floats and how can I add if I have already defined a class?
The code I have so far....

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <p class="mytitle" align="center"><strong>Information</strong></p>
              <p><br></p>
              <p class="info-news"><img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18"   height="20"><a href="http://example.com/information_id=4" target="">Our team</a></p>
              <p class="infonews"><img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18" height="20"> <a href="http://example.com/information_id=6" target="">Couriers</a></p>
              <p class="infonews"><img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18" height="20">   <a href="http://example.com/information_id=8" target="">Refunds</a></p>

          <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
              <div id="signup">
                  <a href="http://http://example.com/signup.php"><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="image/catalog/signupbox.png" width="405" height="200"></a>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: closing `</div>` missing right before `<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">`

Comment: OK, I though all </div> closes went at the end and I had added enough, What happens when a div isn't closed off? The div code doesn't execute properly?

Comment: calculate open `<div>` its 5 and closed `</div>` it's 4 so I don't see it closing went at the end and if div isn't closed off properly then it will take other `<div>` elements inside until it will find first available `</div>` close tag , in your case scenario `<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">` is coming inside `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` which it shouldn't reason, it's like murdering the bootstrap grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Answer (score 1):

As Shehary mentioned your first column is missing the closing `</div>` tag.

Also try adding classes to the columns for large screens (col-lg-6). See example below:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <p class="mytitle" align="center"><strong>Information</strong></p>
        <p><br></p>
        <p class="info-news"><img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18"   height="20"><a href="http://example.com/information_id=4" target="">Our team</a></p>
        <p class="infonews"><img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18" height="20"> <a href="http://example.com/information_id=6" target="">Couriers</a></p>
        <p class="infonews"><img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18" height="20">   <a href="http://example.com/information_id=8" target="">Refunds</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs col-lg-6">
        <div id="signup">
            <a href="http://http://example.com/signup.php"><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="image/catalog/signupbox.png" width="405" height="200"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can achieve what you are trying to achieve without writing custom CSS using [bootstrap grid examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic). Also Bootstrap has per-defined classes which you can use e.g

Here you align the text in center

```
<p class="mytitle" align="center"><strong>Information</strong></p>
```

but you don't need `align="center"`, bootstrap has it's per-defined class for it `class="text-center"` assigned to any element will bring it into center.

```
<p class="mytitle text-center"><strong>Information</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me, please try.. NO floats etc needs to be added :)

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <p class="mytitle" align="center"><strong>Information</strong></p>
          <p class="info-news">
            <img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18"   height="20">
            <a href="http://example.com/information_id=4" target="">
                Our team
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class="infonews">
            <img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18" height="20"> 
            <a href="http://example.com/information_id=6" target="">
                Couriers
            </a>
          </p>
          <p class="infonews">
            <img src="image/catalog/bullet.png" width="18" height="20">   
            <a href="http://example.com/information_id=8" target="">
                Refunds
            </a>
          </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
  <div id="signup">
   <a href="http://http://example.com/signup.php"><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="image/catalog/signupbox.png" width="405" height="200"></a>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```